# Add "\n" to specific line in text

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i have a textfile with something like this:

`Områder dorsalt i overgangssonen, midtre tredjedel med blodpunkter.R: Malignitet ikke påvist`

How can i add a `\n` before each `R:` in the text for several documents?
This is the code i have so far:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        if name != "merge_reports_into_metadata_csv.py" or name != "BakgrunnsData_v2.csv" or name != "remove_text_windows.py":
            slash = "\\"
            if root == ".":
                slash = ""
            f = open(root.strip(".").strip("\\") + slash + name, "r")
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            f = open(root.strip(".").strip("\\") + slash + name, "w")
            for line in lines:

                if line != "R:" + "\n":
                    f.write(line)
                else:
                    print("adding line space the word 'R:' from " + name)
            f.close()
print("all 'R:'s are moved one line down")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use regex substitution with the `re` module:

```
In [1768]: text = u'Områder dorsalt i overgangssonen, midtre tredjedel med blodpunkter.R: Malignitet ikke påvist'

In [1771]: new_text = re.sub(r'(R:)', r'\n\1', text, flags=re.M)

In [1773]: print(new_text)
Områder dorsalt i overgangssonen, midtre tredjedel med blodpunkter.
R: Malignitet ikke påvist
```

You can read your file at once with `f.read()` and pass the text to `re.sub`.

If your file is rather large, I would recommend reading line by line and writing each line as it is replaced to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can do this by a simple text replace:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

text = "Områder dorsalt i overgangssonen, midtre tredjedel " \
       "med blodpunkter.R: Malignitet ikke påvist\n"

print text.replace("R:", "\nR:")
```

If your pattern is more complex, or if it has spaces around it on occasions, then the other answers mentioning regular expressions are a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all "R:" in text and

```
text.replace('R:','\nR:')
```